# How to generate auto increment values for my duplicate column in my sql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

How to display when i was run to find  duplicate values from my table at this time i want to add new column in select statement  with auto increment values

```
SELECT * FROM tutorials_tbl
WHERE Lscno IN (
SELECT Lscno
FROM tutorials_tbl
GROUP BY Lscno
HAVING COUNT(Lscno) > 1
)ORDER BY Lscno

ID       Title          LSCNo
10       titl_14    000000/06/3/1944
19       titl_13    000000/06/3/19
561     titl_1      000000/10/125/1955
671     titl_1      000000/10/125/1955
1765    titl_1      000000/06/65/1976
1834    titl_1      000000/06/65/1976
1909    titl_1      000000/06/3/1971
1910    titl_1      000000/06/3/1971

 **Excepted output like** in MY SQL ?




 Add
NewCol    ID    Title   LSCNo
  1       10    titl_14 000000/06/3/1944
  2       19    titl_13 000000/06/3/19
  3       561   titl_1  000000/10/125/1955
  4       671   titl_1  000000/10/125/1955
  5       1765  titl_1  000000/06/65/1976
  6       1834  titl_1  000000/06/65/1976
  7       1909  titl_1  000000/06/3/1971
  8       1910  titl_1  000000/06/3/1971
```

Comment: You just [cross-posted this on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599037/how-to-generate-auto-increment-values-column-when-select-statement-run-in-my-sql). Please post to one site.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, execute one at a time set variable and select statement.

```
SET @Variable:=0;
SELECT @Variable:=@Variable+1 AS AddNewColumn,ID,Title,Lscno 
FROM tutorials_tbl
WHERE Lscno IN (
    SELECT Lscno
    FROM tutorials_tbl
    GROUP BY Lscno
    HAVING COUNT(Lscno) > 1
)ORDER BY Lscno
```

Comment: if answer is right ,please tick  answer is correct

Answer (score 0):

try this

`SELECT 
    @i:=@i+1 AS iterator, 
    t.ID, t.Title ,t.LSCNo
FROM 
    (SELECT ID, Title, LSCNo FROM tutorials_tbl
WHERE Lscno IN (
SELECT Lscno
FROM tutorials_tbl
GROUP BY Lscno
HAVING COUNT(Lscno) > 1
)ORDER BY Lscno) AS t,
    (SELECT @i:=0) AS foo`

Comment: check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql)